# Using buffer for read and read operations examples in Go

Tags: go, buffer

my os background is not strong, could someone provide some examples (in Go please if possible), why using buffer is important?

Comment: This question is a tiny little bit unspecific, so the answer might be a bit unspecific too: User buffering to speed up stuff. Some things are "not efficient" or "painful to do right" if done unbuffered. See e.g. package bufio for examples of both.

Comment: Thanks @Volker. Thats true, my question is unspecific. But I asked it from curiosity, not real need. I want to learn something new :)

Comment: @Sławosz: The Stack Overflow Q&A format is for specific questions that have short factual answers. For example: I am reading a large file sequentially. Should I or shouldn't I buffier I/O, and why? You are asking for a treatise on buffering. That's far too much to ask for.

Comment: @peterSO I know, but what is different way to get basic knowledge about specific topic fast?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about IO:

Imagine you have a [`var fin *os.File`](http://golang.org/pkg/os/#File) and that file wrapped in a buffer, [`var instrm *bufio.Reader`](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Reader). Now imagine you are writing some kind of parser that reads the input one character (lets say byte) at a time. Package [bufio](http://golang.org/pkg/bufio/) implements buffered I/O.

If you call `myParser.Parse(fin)` you will call `.Read` 4,194,304 times to read each byte, which will make a system call 4,194,304 times, which will cause 4,194,304 [context switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch). [context switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) are when control transfers from the userspace program to the OS and are one of the slowest (non-IO) operations. In situations where the OS is not coalescing/prefetching IO requests there is also the horrible possibility your IO device is seeking and reading one byte at a time, but most operating system's [IO elevator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevator_algorithm), prefetching and [device-side buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_buffer) prevent this nowadays (but it is always better to read in large sequential batches).

If you call `myParser.Parse(instrm)` with the default `bufio.Reader` buffer being 4K you will cause 1,024 context switches (each system call reads 4K rather than 1 byte). Since each system call has some overhead, this will mean less time is spent making system calls and more time for your program to run. It is also worth pointing out that running this way (without the extra context switches) will often increase the [CPU instruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_cache) cache hit rate since more time will be spent [branching within a smaller region of memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference).

Buffers are even important in areas like network IO as it will allow you to send bursts of packets at the maximum [MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) size rather than sending a trickle of tiny packets.

Just don't forget to flush your write buffers.